# Creating dynamically named outputs for wildcarded entry files

Tags: gulp, glob, webpack-4

How can I keep folder structures and filenames?

The preservation of the wildcard `**/*.js` is important. I want to keep it dynamic and not add new components manually.

Folder structure

```
|-- src
    |-- components
        |-- lightbox
            |-- index.js
        |-- carousel
            |-- index.js
        |-- modal
            |-- index.js
```

**Expected** output of folders and files: 
*The folder structure and original filenames should be preserved!*

```
|-- build
    |-- components
        |-- lightbox
            |-- index.js
        |-- carousel
            |-- index.js
        |-- modal
            |-- index.js
```

With the current webpack config, I get the following result:
*All components have been put together in a single .js file, which should **not** be.*

```
|-- build
    |-- components
        |-- main.js
```

My webpack config

```
entry: $.glob.sync('./src/components/**/*.js'),
mode: 'development',
output: {
  filename: '[name].js'
},
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/) state that:

> Note this option is called filename but you are still allowed to use something like 'js/[name]/bundle.js' to create a folder structure.

So if your webpack's output filename is `dirA/fileA`, it'll be output to

```
|-- dist
    |-- dirA
         |-- fileA.js
```

But you also state that

> The preservation of the wildcard **/*.js is important

We can take advantage of the fact that you can name your file by passing an object to webpack's entry.

I assume you're using node's `glob` (the `$.glob.sync` confused me a bit), whose output is an array of paths that match the glob patterns. Then, we simply need to modify this array into an object with this format:

```
//from    
["./src/dirA/fileA.js", "./src/dirB/fileB.js"]
// to
{ 
  "dirA/fileA": "./src/dirA/fileA.js",
  "dirB/fileB": "./src/dirB/fileB.js",
}
```

Here's a simple example:

```
const glob = require('glob');

const entry = glob.sync('./src/**/*.js').reduce((entry, path) => {
  const pathName = path.replace(/(\.\/src\/|\.js)/g, ''); // remove `./src/`, `.js`
  entry[pathName] = path;
  return entry;
}, {});

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry,
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
}
```